# Vue.js 3 What is the correct way to initialize my number variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, types, vuejs3

Using Vue 3, I'm getting the following error:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

This is the relevant code:

```
interface ComponentState {
  heroSelected: number;
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Battle',
  setup() {
    const state: ComponentState = reactive({
      heroSelected: null,
```

I also tried `undefined` instead of `null`. I do not want to initialize my variable `heroSelected` to 0 or any other numerical value (in which case I don't get any error).

So what can I do to initialize it in a way that doesn't trigger an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `interface` should be defined as follows :

```
interface ComponentState {
  heroSelected: number | null| undefined;
}
```